# android error in Android Document?

Tags: android, static, abstract-class

this might sound odd, either Im not considering something really basic, or there's a mistake in android documents on Database:
here's the code directly copy/past from documents:

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";

    }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
The member type FeedEntry cannot be declared static; static types can only be declared in static or top level types
```

why would such a mistake happen in google's dosuments?
thanks for your time.

Comment: `final static class FeedReaderContract` instead of `final class FeedReaderContract`

Comment: @MD whats with the Google's documents then ? is these kind of basic errors common ?

Comment: u can not access static variable outside class. if u want then your parent must be static. in short u can access static variable only from static classe

Comment: @MD noted, but the question is: shouldn't  Google's Document be Error-less ? please provide your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sometimes mistakes available Google's Document e.i. Typo,classes etc... i saw many many such a mistakes into Google's Document